# using apply to readd value back into orginal dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I applogize in advance as this question is partly technical and partly understanding better pandas/python design.

Here's what I'm trying to do. Give this data:

```
a,b
1,2
1,3
2,4
2,5
```

I want to create a third column ['c'] with some data based on each column and grouping of A. The way I have done it is:

```
for item in df.a.unique(): 
   dataSetToProcess = df.loc[df['a'] == item][['a', 'b']]
   dataSetToProcess['c'] = dataSetToProcess.apply(MyFunction)
```

with this approach, I have a value for C but it's only on dataSetToProcess which is not part of the main DF. I would like to have the value of C available in the main DF.

my expected results(for simplicity of example, let's say each group of column A just averages the group itself and adds it to column C):

```
a,b,c
1,2, 2.5
1,3, 2.5
2,4, 4.5
2,5, 4.5
```

My two thoughts were to take each result and map column A,B to the original DF but was wondering if there was an easier/cleaner approach?

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there sample of `dataSetToProcess` and expected result?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Thank you. I have updated with a simplified expected result. In my forLoop, datasettoprocess is just created based on unique values on column A.  I need this because my function needs the entire subgroup of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you have two dataframes, `df1` and `dataSetToProcess`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 1, 2, 2], "b": [2, 3, 4, 5]})
dataSetToProcess = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2], "c": [2.5, 4.5]})

print(df1)
print(dataSetToProcess)

   a  b
0  1  2
1  1  3
2  2  4
3  2  5
   a    c
0  1  2.5
1  2  4.5
```

Then:

```
df1 = df1.merge(dataSetToProcess, on="a")
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
   a  b    c
0  1  2  2.5
1  1  3  2.5
2  2  4  4.5
3  2  5  4.5
```

From there, you can compute your variable based on `a`, `b` and `c` columns.